# Event listener on prototype

Tags: javascript, dom-events, prototype

I know this doesn't work:

```
SVGPathElement.prototype.onmouseover=function(){
alert("info");
}
```

I want to add event listener to element's prototype,so every time I create such  element it can automatically get this event listener.How can I do it with prototype like above?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **event delegation**.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
    if(e.target && e.target.nodeName === "path") {
        console.log("SVG Path element clicked);
    }
});
```

You would attach the mouseover event handler to the `body` element and invoke the logic when the node name is the one that you are looking for.